# RSpec, Appium: provide desired capabilities from CLI

Tags: ruby, rspec, appium

I am using this official Appium page http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/default-capabilities-arg/

and I want to override the capabilities which are provided in `spec_helper.rb` this way

```
rspec --default-capabilities spec/test_data/new_caps.json spec/cli_test/cli_test_spec.rb
```

but it is giving me error `invalid option: --default-capabilities`.

Appium server already running in the background.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the version of _Appium_ and upgrade to `1.5+` as necessary.

Comment: I am already using appium version `1.16.0`